# Keeping multiple orders in data.table in R

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a `transaction` table with 50M rows, with a few sample fields as follow:

```
buyer_id  month day hour location seller_id
```

I need to repeatedly sort this table to find the most popular sellers, locations, month etc. per buyer and create a new `summary` table.

I then need to merge the `summary` table to the `transaction` table to find out which sellers are most popular in top frequent locations etc.

Each time, I'll have to re-sort the `transaction table` according to several sets of columns. So I might end up with sorting `setorder(transaction, user_id, month, location)` several times.

I know data.table create order by reference (kinda keep it in a hidden column), without copying the table.

Is there a way to store and refer to these "hidden columns" explicitly, so that I don't have to resort data with so many times in the same way?

Comment: You could set the key with the `physical=FALSE` argument. For instance: `data(iris);setDT(iris);setkey(iris,Petal.Length,physical=FALSE)` then with `attr(iris,"index")` you can refer to the "hidden" order column.

Comment: @nicola: this is nice. How can I use the index in the group_by statements?

Comment: I guess you could make that attribute a part of the data.table as a new column? `iris$idx <- attr(attr(iris, "index"), "Petal.Length")`

But I am not sure if this is very efficient, due to the use of $